# JDBC - Error in communication (MySQL + Netbeans)

Tags: java, mysql

Please ,i use fedora 16  and i working with JDBC  to connect with mysql, i have  this error

'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

```
enter code here

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)``
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
at JDBC.mysql.main(mysql.java:31)'
```

**how i can conect java with MYsql Under fedora ?**

Comment: i hope from **Stackoverflow users**  help me

Comment: can you show the code snippet that give errors?

Comment: You need to add the [ConnectorJ](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) jar (this contains the class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`) in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

First, put you jdbc connector in your classpath.
You can get it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Second, put Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") in the first line of your code to force the class to be loaded.

Any doubts?
Folow [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/) tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but you can clear more , in other words, show steps because I`m beginner in mysql under linux

Comment: Added a tutorial in answer. Don't forget to give +1 at the answer.